# WPML source default language for some WooCommerce products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, translation, wpml

I have an e-shop with some hundreds of products. The default language of the e-shop is English, and there is a second language also. All products are translated to the second language, but there are about 50 products that by mistake were originally inserted to the second language directly and English was set as the translation.

Is there any way to change the source language of those 50 "pairs" of products from the second language to English? My problem is that there are some custom fields in my products, but also the prices etc, cannot be set in the English language, as that being a translation, is considered the "copy" -- their fields are locked, so I have to do all changes to the second language, exactly the opposite that is of what all other products can be edited.

Comment: Try the following: [WPML change default language of already made post](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/wpml-change-default-language-of-already-made-post/#post-3692807)

Comment: You can disconnect a translation from the default language page or post by navigating to the page editor, switching to the secondary language, and updating the translation settings to None before saving. - https://wpml.org/faq/how-to-disconnect-translations-from-the-default-language-page-or-post/